# Delete minimum amount of overlapping circle?

Tags: python, circle-pack

Is there any way to delete the minimum amount of overlapping circle to get maximum amount of non-overlapping circle?

Illustration of problem:

[image]

I want to delete the overlapping circle, but keep the result maximum. For the problem above, the result should be this:

[image]

I've tried to hard code it by creating each circle combination then calculate number of intersects and disjoints. However, this takes too long. Is there's any quick solution for this kind of problem?

Comment: I found a solution here, https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/35876/maximum-non-intersecting-subset-of-circles, anyone could explain it pls?

Comment: The answer of D.W. on the link you provided is indeed a nice way to solve it. The variables `x_i` have a binary value: 0 is non selected circle, 1 is selected circle. You want to maximize the number of selected circles, so to maximize the sum `x_1+...+x_n`. The constraints ensure that two overlapping circles cannot be selected together. There are on-the-shelf minimizers for these kind of integer linear programming problems

Comment: You can have a look at [this tutorial](https://realpython.com/linear-programming-python/). It seems that PuLP does the job

Comment: Currently I'm still learning myself backtracking then I'll learn the ILP. It's because I'm not from cs background, thus I don't know this kind of way of programming. Thanks Romain, I'll use the source for learning later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this it should work ;) You need to install `pulp`. The script is divided into 3 parts:

- parametrization of your problem
- random generation of circles (I made random radii, but you can use fixed radii if necessary)
- solution with `pulp`

```py
from pulp import LpMaximize, LpProblem, LpStatus, lpSum, LpVariable
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.random import rand

#%% PARAMETRIZE the PROBLEM
N = 10 # number of circles
X = 15 # size on X
Y = 15 # size on Y

Rmin = 1 # min radius
Rmax = 2 # max radius

#%% GENERATE RANDOM CIRCLES

cx = rand(N)*(X-2*Rmax) + Rmax
cy = rand(N)*(Y-2*Rmax) + Rmax
r  = rand(N)*(Rmax-Rmin) + Rmin

plt.figure(1)
plt.clf()
for i in range(N): plt.gca().add_artist(plt.Circle((cx[i], cy[i]), r[i], alpha=0.7))
plt.axis('image')
plt.xlim(0,X)
plt.ylim(0,Y)


#%% GET SOLUTION
model = LpProblem(name="small-problem", sense=LpMaximize)
var = [LpVariable(name="x%u"%i, lowBound=0,upBound=1,cat='Integer') for i in range(N)]

# Add objective function to model
model += lpSum(var)

# Add constraints
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(i+1,N):
        dij = np.sqrt((cx[i]-cx[j])**2 + (cy[i]-cy[j])**2)
        if dij < (r[i]+r[j]):
            model += (var[i]+var[j]<=1,"intersec %u - %u"%(i,j))


# Solve it
status = model.solve()
print(f"status: {model.status}, {LpStatus[model.status]}")
print(f"objective: {model.objective.value()}")
for v in model.variables():
    print(f"{v.name}: {v.value()}")
    if v.value():
        i = int(v.name[1])
        plt.gca().add_artist(plt.Circle((cx[i], cy[i]), r[i],fc='none',ec='C1',lw=2))
```

Comment: Is it possible to give all possible solutions rather than only one solution?

Comment: Maybe it exists but I didn't see it. You can have a look at the documentation of `pulp`. Otherwise, once you have found a solution you can add a constraint to eliminate it, run the algorithm again, get the new solution, add a constraint to eliminate it... etc... until there is no solution any more. It is an iterative process

Comment: Nevertheless the complexity increases. Minimizers are often good at finding one solution, but to get all solutions is a more difficult task

Comment: Let's say your solution is `(x_i,x_j,x_k)`. The constraint that removes this solution is `x_i+x_j+x_k<3`. So the ILP minimizer will find another solution with same number of elements (alternative solution) or a solution with less elements (this is a stopping criterion since it is a worse solution)

Comment: Ok I understand what you meant. I'll try to approach using backtracking first, and then  compare it with using ILP iteratively. Thanks Romain.